# Angular upgrading to bootstrap 5 for existing project, referencing bootstrap 5

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular upgrade project.
Just to be sure we had the proper libs (as we had many incompatibility issues, first all packages where installed, and packages with problems have been skipped so we have a good starting base with all compatible libs.. (we found some modern replacements to fix the incompatibilities)
And i can see from the package-lock.json that version 5.3.1 is installed.

```
 },
    "node_modules/bootstrap": {
      "version": "5.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-5.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jzwza3Yagduci2x0rr9MeFSORjcHpt0lRZukZPZQJT1Dth5qzV7XcgGqYzi39KGAVYR8QEDVoO0ubFKOxzMG+g==",
      "funding": [
        {
          "type": "github",
          "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/twbs"
        },
        {
          "type": "opencollective",
          "url": "https://opencollective.com/bootstrap"
        }
      ],
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8"
      }
    }
```

However when i download from the bootstrap 5 site, example navigation menu's.
Then they like our navigation are  shown vertically, this indicates to me that something is wrong.
Inspecting the \node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js fiels showed in the js files license that its indeed v5.3.1
But i have strong doubts that it is in use (others who fail with bootstrap often fail on <nav menus too)

Although other things might apply i wonder Where in an originally bootstrap 4 prj the references are top load bootstrap, its in my package.json but maybe since code was copied in after the package installs, a reference should be in place that now isnt there. (and maybe normally multiple such references exist)

the code makes use of ng-bootstrap

I checked my code, but did not found references, and i'm curious as to how/where it should be, and maybe there are multiple places for it ?/

Comment: From bootstrap 4 to bootstrap 5 there're are a laaarge step and [breaking changes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#v500). But firstly, check your `angular.json` to see what .css and .js are you using.

Comment: on type of the angular json just after schema i have: 
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "src/styles.css",
    "../node_modules/ngx-ui-switch/ui-switch.component.css"
  ]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the cross compatible versions of Angular, NGB, and Bootstrap.

```
NGB     Angular Bootstrap
12.x.x  13.0.0  5.0.0 
13.x.x  14.1.0  5.2.0
14.x.x  15.0.0  5.2.3
15.x.x  16.0.0  5.2.3
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: i'm on bootstrap  "bootstrap": "^5.3.2" (which seems ok, above minimal 5.2.3) and I am on  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.1", and  "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.1",

Comment: If you're on NGB v15, you should be on the latest Angular, v16. Not seeing which version you're on, so do double check that you don't need to downgrade on NGB, or upgrade Angular.

Comment: I added to my /src/style.css file on top  `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";` now it loads, though i am kinda suprized as bootstrap 4 didnt had the file as that, which makes me also wonder if there are more places to add it, and if i'm doing it at the right place now (although the menu works now).

Comment: That's the only place I remember ever adding it, but as you say: weird if it worked without it... ?

Answer (score 0):

I added below to my **/src/style.css** file on top
`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

Now it loads, though I am kind of surprised as Bootstrap 4 didn't have the file as that, which makes me also wonder if there are more places to add it and if I'm doing it at the right place now (although the menu works now). However after that bootstrap 5 was recognized, and the menus worked.

Answer (score 0):

use the angular.json file to add css and scrips

```
    "styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "src/styles.css"
    ],
```

dont forget to add the script as well

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: I dont know why but for me that didnt work, although i think it should work too (normally) adding it to styles.css worked for me, also only in there i could add font awesome in a similair way.

Comment: the above is the proper way to add css, check the path. I also advise u to use the bootstrap.min.js file for better performance. further the bootstrap js handle clicks, dropdowns, responsive menu and more, u have to add it